# MQTT server in Haskell

Tags: haskell, mqtt

I would like to implement an MQTT server in Haskell.

I already have a HTTP REST server made in Haskell and would like to add some MQTT endpoints to that server.
For instance, there is an endpoint `POST /foo`, allowing users to send some information that will be stored in a Mongo DB. I would like to add an MQTT endpoint: if someone performs a `PUBLISH` with topic `"/foo"`, the data will be stored to the same Mongo database, using the same internal functions than the `POST`.
Similarly for the `SUBSCRIBE`, the data should come from the backend database.

I saw http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mqtt-0.1.1.0
and
https://github.com/lpeterse/haskell-hummingbird
But I'm not sure if they are useable as a library to create the endpoints with specific callbacks.

So this is a two-fold question:

1. Any feedback on implementing MQTT endpoints in Haskell?
2. Is merging an HTTP and MQTT servers a good idea?

Comment: I voted to close as too broad.  There isn't any one question here.  Perhaps this is like a quest for thoughts from people with similar experiences?

Comment: You need to read the spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html but be aware the HTTP model will not match at all.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I tried to add more specific questions. There is not much material with MQTT in Haskell, sorry for the broad question.

Comment: @hardillb what do you mean not match at all? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Pub/Sub != Request/Response the whole paradigm is different (1 to many clients exchange messages, rather than 1 client request resource from server) , topics != URI resource requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, here are my findings on MQTT in Haskell:

First library I found is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mqtt-hs. However it is buggy and not maintained anymore.
I'm now using http://hackage.haskell.org/package/net-mqtt, which works well.

I also understood that I didn't need to make a MQTT server: I just need to develop a client! My MQTT client will subscribe on a standard MQTT server (Mosquitto), and sink the data received in my database.

Another pain point of MQTT is the authentication/authorization. My server uses Keycloak for access control, while Mosquitto uses a static ACL file. I solved this problem by developing an authorization proxy for MQTT: the proxy sits in front of Mosquitto and filter the requests, based on Keycloak decisions.

Comment: Mosquitto has a authentication plugin interface that allows you to implement your own authentication mechanism.

Comment: @hardillb any links?